# Codelite crashes after clicking new workspace or creating new project in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, codelite

I am on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and alothough I'm not entirely new to Linux, ***I'm*** a complete newbie to using Codelite on linux.
I've got codelite up and running on Windows with no problems at all. However, its installation on Ubuntu installation seems to have gone awry somewhere.
Because, whenever I fire up Codelite on Ubuntu, it starts alright (seemingly) and then if I try to create a new workspace or even a new project, it simply closes down without any alerts or messages whatsoever. I've searched on the internet about this problem but it seems that nobody has this kind of problem. So either I'm doing something basically stupid or my Ubuntu is not well. Either way, I will be very grateful if someone could guide me and set me straight.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Its not you. Its Ubuntu's fault.
The codelite provided by Ubuntu is very ancient (2.8). The current version is 6.1.1

To fix your problem:

- Uninstall CodeLite `sudo aptitude purge codelite codelite-plugins`
- Install new CodeLite provided by The CodeLite Team from [our repository](http://codelite.org/LiteEditor/Repositories#toc1)

Note that We filed a bug to Ubuntu to remove this broken package... but nothing was done to fix this

Comment: That's what I found out when I took a close look at the version of Codelite supplied in the Software Center. Thanks for the link, that should sort me out for good.

Answer (score 0):

That worked for me:

1. Download the .deb file from [here](http://downloads.codelite.org/).
2. Run `sudo dpkg -i codelite-x.y.z.deb` (this install the package)
3. Run `sudo apt-get install -f` (this fixes all dependency issues)

Thanks to [xuancong84](https://github.com/xuancong84), instruction took from [this issue](https://github.com/eranif/codelite/issues/1228).