# CMake Error: Could not create named generator CodeLite - Unix Makefiles

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, codelite

Using Ubuntu LTS 14.04.
Trying to set up codelite to develop in c++ following this tutorial [TheChernoProject How to Setup C++ on Linux](https://youtu.be/LKLuvoY6U0I)

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.5)

project (HelloWorld)

set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -Werror -std=c++14")
set (source_dir "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/")

file (GLOB source_files "${source_dir}/*.cpp")

add_executable (HelloWorld ${source_files})
```

build.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

cmake -G "CodeLite - Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
```

EDIT:
After consulting the Documentation https://github.com/eranif/codelite I modified build.sh to:

```
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
```

and it worked. and gave the output:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.4
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.4
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
```

However the HelloWorld workspace was not generated

Comment: Is that the entire error, no other context?

Comment: Yes, that’s all the terminal’s output when I run build.sh

Comment: I got the same error. Running Linux Mint 18.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a fresh project from scratch purely using CodeLite and it generated the CMake file for me. Everything worked flawlessly.

Comment: For some reason, codelite crashes every time I try to create a new project

Comment: Ah! I found this for you:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26603375/codelite-crashes-after-clicking-new-workspace-or-creating-new-project-in-ubuntu

Comment: This was exactly what I needed.After creating a workspace, and making a new project, everything builds and runs as expected.